# Speedup median in dax(ssas)

Tags: performance, statistics, dax, median

I m using the dax function median.
It works well on small dataset but on large table it is super slow.
I'm doing the median of salary on a table that contains 300 millions rows.
Is there a way to speed up the median in dax ?

Thanks

Comment: Computing a median is pretty expensive even with the best algorithms. Often, it require to do several expensive partitions internally. What do you mean by slow: how long does it take? To compare the performance with a relatively fast (but sub-optimal) implementation, you can run `np.median(col)` where `col` is `np.ascontiguousarray(pandas_column.to_numpy())`

Comment: Do also share your DAX expression as there maybe other factors at play.

Comment: It s in Microsoft dax not Python. By slow I mean 2 minutes and sometimes even more,depending on the data you want to show.
Is there an alternative to the native dax median function?

Comment: Based on the timings, it looks like they use an inefficient sort. I provided an alternative solution already in the first comment.

Comment: ok, could you explain.several partitions ? How can I implement that in dax?